# PDO exception while sending request from inside a container

Tags: php, mysql, docker, docker-compose

**First situation:**

I run the `php artisan migrate` command from a terminal on a laravel project, and it works fine updating the mysql database on 
`127.0.0.1:3306`. This means that the php-mysql connection was fine.

**Second situation:**

Running the project inside a docker container I was not able to set 
the database to `127.0.0.1` since in a docker container that matches 
the container itself. I read that docker has a bridge to connect 
   with the host (in the case of Linux `172.17.0.1`). So I changed the mysql 
   connection settings to `172.17.0.1:3306`. And I get:

> PDOException
>      Packets out of order. Expected 0 received 1. Packet size=69

and

> PDOException SQLSTATE[HY000] [2006] MySQL server has gone away.

**Question:**

Why does it work with `127.0.0.1` but from not from inside a container?

Comment: Containers have their networking walled off. You need to use an IP the container has access to.

Comment: using ip addr show i get this: docker0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default 
    link/ether 02:42:d9:29:0d:56 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.17.0.1/16 brd 172.17.255.255 scope global docker0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

Comment: I'm using the bridge IP.

Comment: If your database is bound to 127.0.0.1 it's not accessible inside of Docker. You'll need to bind to 0.0.0.0 but be aware this makes it accessible to everyone who can poke your machine's IP.

Comment: You can always spin up the database inside of Docker, too then use that container's IP instead. `docker-compose` makes this fairly easy to link up.

Comment: I've try already the bind-addr = 0.0.0.0 and get the same error. I will try using a container for the database.

Comment: If you can wrangle this all into a single Docker Compose config file it usually works out perfectly. Otherwise it's a lot of trial-and-error. Hope that works!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201772/discussion-between-armando-rodriguez-acosta-and-tadman).

Comment: what are PHP and MySQL images you are starting FROM?

Comment: I already solve this by creating a LAMP container serving as DB server. And using docker networking.